# Dividing a space in a given number of cells depending on its size

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, layout, p5.js

I recently started coding using P5.js and the browser editor they provide. You can find the code I'm talking about below at https://editor.p5js.org/Y_P/sketches/Xo2exzHSX

1- I'm looking for an algorithm to split a given screen space optimally into rows and columns so it follows the ratio. The inputs would be the width/height of the space, and the minimum number of cells you want. It would return the row and column that would be optimal to fit those cells.
My first iteration seems to work but favor ratio offset too much. I'm curious about other options that might exist and be more efficient.

2- I would also like to make a function to constrain the ratio in a certain range and can't wrap my head around it.

Is anyone good enough in Math or any knows an HTML/JS function I could use? :)

EDIT: I put the code right there because in case you don't want to follow the link above:

```
function setup() {

  spaceW = 1600;
  spaceH = 500;
  unit = 30;

  //constrainRatio(700, 200, 0.5, 1.5);

  createCanvas(spaceW, spaceH);
  background(51);

  let division = divideSpace(spaceW, spaceH, unit);
  for (let i = 0; i < division.x; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < division.y; j++) {
      rect(spaceW * i / division.x, spaceH * j / division.y, spaceW / division.x, spaceH / division.y);
    }
  }
}

function divideSpace(w, h, unit) {
  base = ceil(sqrt(unit));

  if (round(w / h) != 1) {
    if (h < w) {
      ratio = h / w;
      column = ceil(ratio * base);
      row = ceil(unit / column);
    } else if (h > w) {
      ratio = w / h;
      row = ceil(ratio * base);
      column = ceil(unit / row);
    }
  } else {
    row = base;
    column = base;
  }
  return createVector(row, column);
}
```

Comment: This is not the place to ask for solutions without providing an example of what you tried. Please read the FAQ before posting questions.

Comment: I did add a link to my code, and just in case, I also added it directly in the thread now.

Comment: 'I'm looking for an algorithm to split a given screen space optimally into rows and columns so it follows the ratio' This code seems to do exactly that, so, well done there. What do you mean by 'favor ratio offset too much'? I don't get what the problem is here.
p5 does have a build-in function https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/constrain, Maybe that (or the source code) gives an idea of how to contrain values?